# How to set up HasDispatchingFragmentInjector in dagger.android tests?

Tags: android, dagger-2

The [documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) doesn't describe how to do that, as far as I can understand.

I have a Fragment invoking AndroidSupportInjection.inject in its onAttach method. Looking at the implementation of that method, it seems like I would have to ensure the Fragment is added to an activity that implements HasDispatch(Support)FragmentInjector, perhaps something like https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/javatests/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionTest.java#L60. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: How are you testing your fragments now? Are you testing their logic without attaching them to anything, or using a testing framework like Robolectric to simulate Android lifecycle, or attaching them in real emulators? Also, note the switch to an AndroidInjector _interface_ in [this commit](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/9bdbb54a07958ad92ab21c69c630cd4783956b16), with a matching rename from HasDispatchingFragmentInjector to HasFragmentInjector, with the express benefit of making it easier to fake in tests.

Comment: We're using Roboelectric and testing them with the lifecycle. We've come up with two pretty different approaches, none of which I'm super happy with (one is a common testing activity that I find bloated, the other needs to jump through a lot of hoops to create a DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>). I think the interface-based solution would be a win for us, based on the code we've written so far.

Comment: I'd agree. You have lightweight unit tests, so writing a fake AndroidInjector sounds much more palatable than invoking Dagger or using other heavy infrastructure. Use Dagger 2.11-rc1 to get access to AndroidInjector.